# Convert String to Date in .NET if my incoming date format is in YYYYMMDD

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

What is the best way to convert string to date in C# if my incoming date format is in `YYYYMMDD`

Ex: `20001106`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use DateTime.ParseExact(). Something like:

```
   string date = "20100102";
   DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @Dynami try again, I just edited with the proper format (case matters)

Comment: As per Luke's solution it works fine date format should be 'yyyyMMdd' else is thowing expection 'string was not recognized as a valid datetime'

Answer (score 11):

```
 DateTime.TryParseExact(myDateString, "yyyyMMdd", 
                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                         DateTimeStyles.None, out myDateVar )
```

Comment: I used this method since it allowed me to check the return value of TryParseExact and know if the date converted properly.  I set a default when it did not.

Answer (score 4):

Check [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) with a pattern string of `"yyyyMMdd"` if you are on .NET 2.0 or better.

If you are stuck with .NET 1.1 use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

see [Standard DateTime Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(VS.80).aspx) for the rules for making pattern strings.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime yourDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(yourString, "yyyyMMdd", null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using TryParseExact is generally nicer than ParseExact as it won't throw an exception if the conversion fails.  Instead it returns true if it's successful, false if it's not:

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("20100202", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
   Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
}
```