# Convert String to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string like this:

```
"20090212"
```

and I want to convert to valid C# datetime.

Do I need to parse it out because that seems too much work?

Comment: Fastest finger first ... That's a surprisingly useful question (I have to search my own code the answer when I'm doing that), but there'll be a handful of answers within in the first minute ...

Comment: Exact duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188585/convert-string-to-date-in-c/2188593#2188593

Comment: @Dynami It never came in the search results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
DateTime result =
    DateTime.ParseExact("20090212", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: nice tip, will definitely come in handy sometime

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the DateTime.TryParseExact method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)).  I prefer TryParseExact method to the ParseExact method because it returns a boolean telling you whether or not the conversion was successful instead of throwing an exception but either one will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

... and I really doubt I got there first.

Although for completeness, I prefer `TryParseExact`

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)) { 
  // ... use the variable dt 
}
```

Comment: In general, it is safer to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when you know that all input strings will be in a specific format.  Sometimes format codes are interpreted differently when in different locales.