# ISO 8601 into a datetime object using C#

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a .NET DateTime from ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format)

How can I parse a date string in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format into a datetime object using C#?

Comment: Is the source string in `ISO8601` format or do you want to convert a string to that format?

Comment: the source string is in ISO8601 format and I want to convert this string to that format into a datetime object. I have his :DateTime.ParseExact("2011-02-14T13:10:30", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); and the result is 2011-02-14 13:10:30 and I am supposed to get 2011-02-14T13:10:30 or Am I wrong to expect this result?

Answer (score 5):

Use one of the ISO 8601 [standard date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) - ["O", "o"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) , ["S" and "s"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable) when parsing the string (aka the Roundtrip format specifier) .

> The pattern for this specifier reflects a defined standard (ISO 8601). Therefore, it is always the same regardless of the culture used or the format provider supplied.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(iso8601String, "s", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: That bombs when the input string contains the "Z" timezone specifier.