# TryParse special date-format

Tags: c#, datetime

I try to parse a date-time stamp from an external system as following:

```
DateTime expiration;
DateTime.TryParse("2011-04-28T14:00:00", out expiration);
```

Unfortunately it is not recognized. How can I parse this successfully?

sl3dg3

Comment: Try DateTime.TryParseExact() by specifiying the required format

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Specify the exact format you want in [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime expiration;

string text = "2011-04-28T14:00:00";
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(text,
                                      "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                      DateTimeStyles.None,
                                      out expiration);
```

Comment: I only ever use `TryParseExact`. You can't really trust `TryParse` if the computer may be on (gasp) US settings.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead.

[How to create a .NET DateTime from ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DateTime expiration;
DateTime.TryParse("2011-04-28 14:00:00", out expiration);
```

Without using "T".

Comment: Changing the input value (which is supplied elsewhere) isn't nearly as nice a solution as changing how you parse to match the expected format, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append "00000Z" to your string argument.

```
DateTime.TryParse("2011-04-28T14:00:0000000Z", out expiration);
```

Answer (score 1):

User [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx#Y2200) function as following:

```
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue))
{
    // Do Something ..
}
```

---

Read about [DateTime](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx&rct=j&q=csharp%20datetime%20class&ei=Cj65TbucO4is8gPn35w3&usg=AFQjCNHqFQFzlA4FByZb36eNLXsD-xXtUw&cad=rja).