# Time coversion (2013-03-13T18:30:00 CET)

Tags: c#

is That anyway to save this "2013-03-13T18:30:00 CET" into a DateTime without restructuring the whole string ?

anyway to convert it by using Convert.ToDatetime ?

Comment: Other than the time zone part, it's easy to do this with `DateTime.ParseExact`. The "CET" bit is the tricky one.

Comment: That's ISO 8601 format. However [last time that came up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format) there were no great solutions.