# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject throws invalid Globalization date format exception

Tags: c#, json.net

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` throws invalid Globalization date format exception for following date:

```
2016-07-26T24:33:37.177Z
```

**Code**

```
DataTable leadDataTable = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(leadAObj["result"].ToString(),
    typeof(DataTable));
```

I tried by explicitly passing date format

**Code**

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(leadAObj["result"].ToString(), typeof(DataTable),
     new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ" })
```

Comment: Have you tried settings the `JsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString` property to the required datetime format?

Comment: I passed IsodateTimeConverter object as third parameter to Deserialize Object method, 
*New Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ" }*

Comment: That *is* an invalid ISO8601 time. There is no `24:33`, it should be `00:33`. You should fix the code that generates the JSON string

Comment: To put it lightly, the 25th hour may be valid for movies but not for ISO dates

Comment: I'm getting this data from REST api call, with out Deserialize how could I update that data, please suggest some way, I don't have acces to update that api code

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the API, and the API should be fixed. If you have to fix it client side then you'd need to search for the T24 and change it to T00 (and then decide whether the date should be 26th or the 27th) All very  hacky though, better to fix the API?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse()` itself throws an exception when passed a date string like that.  You may have to write your subclass of  `IsoDateTimeConverter` and parse the date string manually.  See [Parsing JSON dates that end in T24:00:00Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640773/parsing-json-dates-that-end-in-t240000z) for a similar question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time is 33 minutes past midnight is that what you are expecting?

Shouldn't it be 00:33 not 24:33