# Format ISO datetime to March 12th, 2014 12:00:00

Tags: c#, date, time, format

How can I turn an ISO date (20140312120000 or 2014-03-12 12:00:00) into "March 12th, 2014 12:00:00"?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like so: DateTime.Parse(isodate).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss").

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse it with the normal DateTime.Parse method,

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd''HHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: That's giving me a System.FormatException saying the format string is invalid. I'm testing on Mono, so it may be a limitation of Mono.

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: The issue is the `'T'` in the string -- remove it.  Your string is not a ISO date/time because its missing 'T'.

Comment: I tried @RichardSchneider's method and it works, but it doesn't give me the desired result. (3/19/2014 21:50:44 PM instead of March 19th, 2014 21:50:44 PM)

Comment: See my answer for the entire answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2014, 3, 12);
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");
// The example displays the following output: 
//    Today is March 12, 2011.
```

Comment: I need the time, too.

Comment: what he needs is to convert the ISO !

Comment: {MMMM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}

Comment: Like @Sajeetharan said, I need to convert it from the ISO format.

Comment: This can be complex and has many current answers have you looked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format for example

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to parse the input string as a `DateTime` and then convert it to the form you want.  The `ParseExact` and `ToString` methods will do the job.

```
public string MyFromat(string s)
{
    var inputForms = new string[] 
    { 
       "yyyyMMdd''HHmmss", 
       "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss"
    };
    var time = DateTime.ParseExact(s, inputForms, , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return time.ToString(""MMMM dd, yyyy HH':'mm':'dd", , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Your two example forms are not `ISO`.  If you want to parse ISO date times, then use `DateTimeOffset` for representing the time and use these input forms:

```
        static readonly string[] Iso8061DateTimeForms = new string[]
        {
               "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss",
               "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'",
               "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmsszzz",
               "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'fffffff",
               "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'fffffff'Z'",
               "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'.'fffffffzzz",
               "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss",
               "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'",
               "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz",
               "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffff",
               "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffff'Z'",
               "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffzzz",
        };
```

The full implementation for parsing an ISO 8061 time is:

```
 public static DateTimeOffset ParseIso8061Time(string s)
 {
    var styles = DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces |
        (s.EndsWith("Z") 
           ? DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal 
           : DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
    return DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, Iso8061DateTimeForms,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, styles);
 }
```