# How to convert ISO 8601 with timezone to C# Datetime?

Tags: javascript, c#, timezone, datetime-format

How can i convert **ISO 8601** with timezone to c# actual (local) datetime format.

my **ISO 8601** date is like "`2016-06-19T19:30:43+04:30`"

and I need something like this "`2016-06-19 16:00:43`"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a .NET DateTime from ISO 8601 format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format)

Comment: i have used it, but it raised error. since in this sample date format is different than mine.  it is "2010-08-20T15:00:00Z" while my date has timezone "2016-06-19T19:30:43+04:30"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since W3c adopted ISO8601 you can use:

```
XmlConvert.ToString Method (DateTime, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)
```

with the XmlDateTimeSerializationMode you can control how you want to date to be processed.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162344(v=vs.110).aspx

and there is the reverse method to convert string to date...

```
XmlConvert.ToDateTime Method (String, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162342(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: i don't want to convert date to string. i need datetime but in c# normal datetime, without any T or Z or timezone value!

Comment: thanks for your answer but it returns error :The string '2016-06-19T21:57:43 04:30' is not a valid AllXsd value.

Comment: your missing the + for the timezone.

Comment: That's right but why? when i check the variable in javascript, i see that it has + before timezone but when i catch it in codebehind, it is a space instead of + !!

Comment: Are you passing the time in a url query string? If you are you need to encode the + first because the + is interpreted as a space. We're now moving away from the subject of this question.  I'm sure an SO search will find questions covering this new issue