# Unable to validate a date string in ISO 8601 date format

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, datetime, iso8601

In asp.net `Date.Now` generates a complete date string:
e.g `"2018-01-17T11:12:42.0544453+00:00"`

I am unable to validate this date string with the following formats.
Can anyone suggest a suitable validation format?

```
Dim formats() As String = {
  "yyyy-MM-dd",
  "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
  "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff",
  "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff",
  "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fffffffZ",
  "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn",
  "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnnZ",
  "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn+|-hh:mm"
}
If Date.TryParseExact("2018-01-17T11:12:42.0544453+00:00", formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
  //Success
End If
```

Comment: Even `Date.TryParse` would succeed, no need to use `ParseExact`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I am using Parse exact because many different strings are checked, this is just an example of one that fails and I am curious why.

Comment: If you're checking that it's valid, then `TryParse` is enough. You only need `TryParseExact` if you're ensuring it meets a given format. Which are you actually aiming for?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to ensure the date is a valid ISO 8601 date format. This can be true even when time/fractions/timeszones are omitted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a .NET DateTime from ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format)

Comment: @AFriend This post is not a duplicate because I was unable to validate the string using the `Z` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to ensure the date is a valid ISO 8601 date format. This can be
>   true even when time/fractions/timeszones are omitted.

You can use the ["O"(Round-trip) format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier)

```
Dim time = "2018-01-17T11:12:42.0544453+00:00"
Dim validDate = Date.TryParseExact(time, "O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt)
```

> The "O" or "o" standard format specifier represents a custom date and
>   time format string using a pattern that preserves time zone
>   information and emits a result string **that complies with ISO 8601**. For
>   `DateTime` values, this format specifier is designed to preserve date
>   and time values along with the `DateTime.Kind` property in text. ...

Side-note: for me `Date.Now.ToString` doesn't return a string in this format. Maybe you have used:

```
Dim time = Date.UtcNow.ToString("o", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Thanks for this Tim. Would this only validate if the timezone is present or is it more forgiving than explicit formats? Would it need to be an additional format string or will it cover several as those mention above?

Comment: @Obsidian: it also parses `"2018-01-17T11:12:42.0544453"` successfully. But read the documentation i've linked. Especially the part at _"takes advantage of three ways that ISO 8601 represents time zone information: ..."_ It's also mentioned there in point three that it parses it if the _"date and time values have no time zone information"_

Comment: This is the magic. Thank you. I was aware of `o` and kind of embarassed I didn't try it. I got to bogged down with `s` and `z`. Shame there is no one universal validator for all ISO formats.