# Getting C# to correctly set the Kind property for a parsed ISO 8601 string

Tags: c#, datetime, iso

I'm struggling to understand why parsing a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) formatted string that is parsed by DateTime's `Parse` method doesn't set the `Kind` property of the new `DateTime` object correctly.  I've reviewed the post [How to create a .NET DateTime from ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format) and in combination with the ISO documentation it appears that the `Parse` method should be able to set the `Kind` value however it's not.

Example:

`Console.Write(System.DateTime.Parse("2018-11-17T01:00:00").Kind);`

Returns: Unspecified

However according to the ISO standard that is a valid format that indicates the value is a local time.

**[Time Zone Section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators)**

> Time zones in ISO 8601 are represented as local time (with the location unspecified), as UTC, or as an offset from UTC.  If no UTC relation information is given with a time representation, the time is assumed to be in local time.

**[Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))**

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset

Even stranger is that adding a Z to the string sets the `Kind` property to Local.

In order to get the `Kind` value set correctly for a UTC string a DateTimeStyle of RoundtripKind is required in the `Parse` method.  However if the Z is removed from the string `Kind` is set to Unspecified again.

Is this a problem with the DateTime class?

Did Microsoft not follow the ISO standard?

Or am I not understanding the ISO standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `DateTime` to parse the string, but use `DateTimeOffset`. You can then use the `LocalDateTime` or `UtcDateTime` property of the generated `DateTimeOffset` to explicitly get the time represented by the string in local time or UTC time. Or you can use the `Offset` property to check whether the string did originally contain a timezone offset or not.

Answer (score 4):

To parse an ISO 8601 string and set `DateTimeKind` appropriately, you can use [`DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles#System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_RoundtripKind) with either [the `o` standard format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) or a custom string that includes [the `K` custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-k-custom-format-specifier).

For example:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourISO8601String, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFFK",
                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

`DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` provides the following behavior:

- If the incoming value has no time zone offset supplied, the resulting `DateTime` will have `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`
- If the incoming value has a time zone offset of `Z`, the resulting `DateTime` will have `DateTimeKind.Utc`
- If the incoming value has a numeric time zone offset, such a `-07:00`, `+01:00`, or even `+00:00`, the resulting `DateTime` will have `DateTimeKind.Local`, and the value will be converted from the time zone offset provided to the local time zone.

Though this works for many cases, the conversion behavior of the third bullet is often undesired, and thus in most cases it is better to parse to a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`.

Answer (score -2):

You can specify explicitly that the string should be interpreted as local time:

```
Console.Write
(
    DateTime.Parse("2018-11-17T01:00:00", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Kind
);
```

Output:

```
Local
```

Comment: I’m trying to account for the incoming string either ending with or without the Z without having to pre-parse it. If I recall I tested that by adding the Z to the end of the string and it either still said Local or Unspecified.