# Newtonsoft deserialize doesn't convert string to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using the Facebook Graph API which is returning a a json object that contains a datetime in a string in the following format: "created_time": "2013-01-25T00:11:02+0000"

The deserialized object contains this datetime: "0001-01-01 00:00:00", which I suppose is the equivalent of null. How can I deserialize the datetime string properly?

Here is my DTO class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using project.DTOs;

namespace project.DTOs.Facebook
{
    public class FacebookCommentResponseDto
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("from")]
        public FacebookUserDto From { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("created_time")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
        public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set;}
    }
    internal class CustomDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
    {
        public CustomDateTimeConverter()
        {
            base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss.fffK";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code where I deserialize the object:

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
```

Comment: That is `ISO 8601` format. If you want a `unix` timestamp (to convert) you could add `date_format=U` as part of your call. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3556188/1797425) there for more about converting the ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Possibly your format is just off a bit? yyyy-MM-ddTH:mm:ss.fffK --> yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffK(added an H and remove an f as the format you are expecting seems to have hours in two digits and miliseconds in two as well)

Comment: Changing the format by adding the H and removing the f didn't work.
How exactly do I add ```date_format=U```?

Comment: @Mattieeec3 Might not help, but rereading, it should be yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK as there are no milliseconds provided.

Comment: I tried that now too, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have `using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;` and `using System.Text.Json.Serialization;`. On `FacebookCommentResponseDto` you use `JsonPropertyName` which belongs to `System.Text` but the converter class `CustomDateTimeConverter` is meant to be used with the `Newtonsoft.Json` attribute `JsonProperty` not with the `System.Text` attribute `JsonPropertyName`. Hence in your code the converter is never called.

One solution ist to remove `using System.Text.Json.Serialization;` and replace `JsonPropertyName` in `FacebookCommentResponseDto` with `JsonProperty`. That means you only use `Newtonsoft.Json` and then the date conversion even works out-of-the-box without a converter. The following test is green:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using Xunit;

namespace XUnitTestProject1
{
    public class TimeFormatUnitTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ParseCreatedTime()
        {
            var timeString = "2013-01-25T00:11:02+0000";
            var json = "{ \"created_time\": \"" + timeString + "\" }";

            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookCommentResponseDto>(json);

            Assert.Equal(DateTime.Parse(timeString), data.CreatedTime);
        }
    }

    public class FacebookCommentResponseDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("created_time")]
        public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain why that's needed (the fact that his converter is for Newtonsoft while attributes are for `System.Text.Json`) and you've covered the answer

Comment: @ColinM Thank you for the suggestion. I edited my post and tried to explain it as well as I can. Feel free to edit it if you think its necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As Marius said,your converter is for Newtonsoft while attributes are for `System.Text.Json`.You could change `[JsonPropertyName]` to `[JsonProperty]`.

Another solution is to custom converter which implements `JsonConverter<DateTime>` in `System.Text.Json`:

1.Converter:

```
public class FacebookCommentResponseDto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("created_time")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
}
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTime));
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString());
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

2.Deserialize:

```
var time = "2013-01-25T00:11:02+0000";
var ID = "1001";                    
var result = "{ \"created_time\": \"" + time + "\", \"id\": \"" + ID + "\" }";
var data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FacebookCommentResponseDto>(result);
```