# Convert ISO 8601 string into TimeZone Info

Tags: c#, datetime, iso8601

My client app is sending me a date string using ISO 8601 format. I can get a DateTime using,

```
DateTime.Parse(date, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

[How to create a .NET DateTime from ISO 8601 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556144/how-to-create-a-net-datetime-from-iso-8601-format)

Now, I wanna know time zone from the string that client is sending. For example, `2022-07-28T01:00:00+02:00` this means client is +2 hours from UTC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the `DateTime` type. It doesn't know the offset. Use the `DateTimeOffset` type.

```
var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(date);
```

Now you can find the offset in the `Offset` property.