# Trying to convert a string to date time format in vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net, datetime, .net-2.0

I can't seem to be able to convert a string that contains date value of "100714 0700" (2010-07-14 7am) to a date format in vb.net 2005

When I attempt to do:

```
        Dim provider As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        strPickupDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtPickupDate.Text, "yymmdd", provider)
```

I get back "1/14/2010 12:07:00 AM"
How can I get a value of "2010-07-14 7:00"  ?

Comment: where is the string coming from, that could do it also

Comment: Its being pulled from the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another link from here on SO that shows how to do this in C#

[Convert String to Date in .NET if my incoming date format is in YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188585/convert-string-to-date-in-net)

In your case you probably also want add the time format:

```
  string s = "100714 0700";
  DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyMMdd hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I read the question to quickly last time, hmmm have you tried something like `strPickupDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtPickupDate.Text, "yy" & "-" & "-" & "mm" & "-" & "dd", provider)`

Comment: I also need the time part included in the output. Would I have to format that seperately?

Comment: no you should be able to put it in there try
strPickupDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtPickupDate.Text, "yy" & "-" & "mm" & "-" & "dd" & " hh" & ":" & "mm" & " tt", provider)

Comment: For DateTime.ParseExact you need to use the format parameter to describe the exact format the date is already in, not the format that you want it to be in after the conversion.  Once the date is converted to a DateTime, you can format it for output however you want.

Comment: o so he should convert strpickupdatetime into a datetime and then convert it into the correct format.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would do.