# F# - Parse dates

Tags: .net, datetime, f#

Very basic question regarding parsing date in F#. I am very new to F# and .NET, so please bear with me.

My date has the format `yyyyMMDD` like `20100503`.

How do I parse this into a `DateTime` type in F#.

I tried `System.DateTime.Parse("20100503");` but get an error.

How do I pass a format string into the Parse method??

ANSWER is - Thanks everyone for the responses.

```
let d = System.DateTime.ParseExact("20100503", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use a custom format string. Try this:

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact("20100503", "yyyymmdd", null);;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime.ParseExact("20100503", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`

Use the ParseExact method and use lowercase d instead of upper.

Answer (score 2):

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156614/trying-to-convert-a-string-to-date-time-format-in-vb-net-2005/4157120#4157120) this morning.  I have not used F#, but if you have access to DateTime.ParseExact, my answer might help you.

You might also consider TryParseExact so that you can trap a failure based on the function returning false rather than having to put it inside of a try catch:

```
//Using code example from my previous answer...
string s = "100714 0700"; 
DateTime d;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyMMdd hhmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{
  // Whoops!  Something is wrong with the date.
}


//In your case
string s = "20100503"; 
DateTime d;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{
  // Whoops!  Something is wrong with the date.
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion to use TryParseExact. F# usage is different from C# though. It returns both success and the result at once: `match DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None) with | true,d -> d | false,_ -> DateTime.Now`. If you don't mind I will add this below your C# versions.

Answer (score 0):

The format is not one that is accepted.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

You might need to manipulate the string before parsing.

you are on the right track though.

Comment: I think you meant to comment this on my answer. There a variety of properties you can set on the DateTimeFormatInfo object you create, I believe the one you would want to set is ShortDate, I have to warn you, I don't know if this will work with NO separator. Which is why I would just manipulate the string as both answers have suggested.

Comment: You will need to put the string into a format that DateTime.Parse can use. Try changing it to YYYY-MM-DD. You can others have said use DateTime.ParseExact as well which will give you control over the format.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the overload of DateTime.Parse which takes an IFormatProvider. The IFormatProvider you supply must understand that format.

You can do this by creating a DateTimeFormatInfo object with the correct format for the date string you are feeding to parse.

This is probably a lot of work for what you're doing. If you can reorganize the string a little first (most likely to a date string with seperators), you'll probably be better off.