# convert string to System.DateTime in F#

Tags: date, f#

if I get a string from the command line and it looks like this:

```
'1-1-2011'
```

how can I convert that string to a DateTime object in F#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# - Parse dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158077/f-parse-dates)

Comment: @Sebastian P - similar, but I don't believe an exact duplicate, the two questions ask how to parse different date formats, which actually leads to different answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do it as simply as this:

```
let dateTime = System.DateTime.Parse "1-1-2011"
```

Answer (score 26):

Depending on your specific need, .NET's [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) class has several static methods for converting strings to `DateTime` instances, these are `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.ParseExact`, and `DateTime.TryParse` and their several overloads.

@7sharp9 demonstrated the most basic way to perform date parsing, with a direct method call to `DateTime.Parse`. But where things get interesting in F# is with `DateTime.TryParse`. Whereas `DateTime.Parse` will throw an exception if the parse fails, the simplest overload of `DateTime.TryParse` has the signature `string * byref<DateTime> -> bool` which will return whether the parse succeeds setting the `byref` argument to the parsed date if true, or to it's default value (`null` in this case) otherwise. However, the syntax for using this in F# is cumbersome (and indeed it's not pleasant from any .NET language), so the F# language was designed with a special feature which allows a much nicer calling convention for methods like these as @Thomas Petricek pointed out.

But even F#'s (bool, result) return type pattern here is not ideal. Most of the time you don't need the default value if a parse fails. A nicer signature for `DateTime.TryParse` would be `string -> option<DateTime>`. Luckily, we can easily extend `DateTime` as we like:

```
type System.DateTime with 
    static member TryParseOption str =
        match DateTime.TryParse str with
        | true, r -> Some(r)
        | _ -> None
```

We use the above extension like so:

```
match System.DateTime.TryParseOption "11/11/11" with 
| Some r -> stdout.WriteLine r
| None -> stdout.WriteLine "none"
```

Which is more consistent with F# conventions (like `List.tryFind`, for example). But even this is can get "better". Notice how we are matching on the *result* of the try parse. Using Partial Active Patterns (of course!), we can wrap a whole class of try parses and move the match to the match case for greater flexibility.  Take the following

```
open System
let (|DateTime|_|) str =
    match DateTime.TryParse str with
    | true, dt -> Some(dt)
    | _ -> None

let (|Int|_|) str =
    match Int32.TryParse str with
    | true, num -> Some(num)
    | _ -> None

let (|Float|_|) str =
    match Double.TryParse str with
    | true, num -> Some(num)
    | _ -> None
```

Using these, we can write a neat little console application:

```
let rec loop() =
    stdout.WriteLine "
Please select an option:
    1) Parse something
    2) Exit
"
    match stdin.ReadLine() with
    | Int 1 -> 
        stdout.WriteLine "Enter something to parse: "
        match stdin.ReadLine() with
        | Int num -> stdout.WriteLine("Successfully parsed int: {0}", num)
        | Float num -> stdout.WriteLine("Successfully parsed float: {0}", num)
        | DateTime dt -> stdout.WriteLine("Successfully parsed DateTime: {0}", dt)
        | _ -> stdout.WriteLine "Parse Failed!"
        loop()
    | Int 2 -> 
        stdout.WriteLine "Now exiting"
    | _ -> 
        stdout.WriteLine "Invalid option, please try again"
        loop()
```

The key thing to notice is the nested match, where `Int`, `Float`, `DateTime` perform their try parses within the same match expression.

There are other neat applications of these active patterns too, for example, we can succinctly simultaneously filter and map a list of date strings

```
> ["11/23/2003"; "not a date"; "1/1/23 23:23pm"] |> Seq.choose(|DateTime|_|);;
val it : seq<DateTime> =
  seq
    [11/23/2003 12:00:00 AM {Date = 11/23/2003 12:00:00 AM;
                             Day = 23;
                             DayOfWeek = Sunday;
                             DayOfYear = 327;
                             Hour = 0;
                             Kind = Unspecified;
                             Millisecond = 0;
                             Minute = 0;
                             Month = 11;
                             Second = 0;
                             Ticks = 632051424000000000L;
                             TimeOfDay = 00:00:00;
                             Year = 2003;};
     1/1/2023 11:23:00 PM {Date = 1/1/2023 12:00:00 AM;
                           Day = 1;
                           DayOfWeek = Sunday;
                           DayOfYear = 1;
                           Hour = 23;
                           Kind = Unspecified;
                           Millisecond = 0;
                           Minute = 23;
                           Month = 1;
                           Second = 0;
                           Ticks = 638082121800000000L;
                           TimeOfDay = 23:23:00;
                           Year = 2023;}]
```

Answer (score 17):

To add one nice thing to what 7sharp9 wrote, if you also want to handle failures, you can write:

```
match System.DateTime.TryParse "1-1-2011" with
| true, date -> printfn "Success: %A" date
| false, _ -> printfn "Failed!"
```

This is not obvious, because the `TryParse` method has a `byref<DateTime>` as the last argument (and it is used using `out` in C#), but F# allows you to call the method like this.

Comment: didn't know it was possible to do this with the out argument, nice