# What is the correct way to call DateTime.TryParse from F#?

Tags: .net, f#, tryparse

What is the correct way to call DateTime.TryParse from F#? I am trying to test some code from F# interactive and I can't figure out how to pass a mutable DateTime into the second argument by ref. What is the in/out/ref syntax in F#?

This is the method signature I'm looking at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: is this a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949941/convert-string-to-system-datetime-in-f

Comment: See [Passing by Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Chris's answer is correct if you really need to pass a mutable `DateTime` by reference.  However, it is much more idiomatic in F# to use the compiler's ability to treat trailing `out` parameters as tupled return values:

```
let couldParse, parsedDate = System.DateTime.TryParse("11/27/2012")
```

Here, the first value is the `bool` return value, while the second is the assigned out parameter.

Comment: results will be on of the following tuples: 
(false, DateTime.MinValue) and (true, DateTime(2012,11,27))

Answer (score 14):

Here's how to execute DateTime.TryParse in F#:

```
let mutable dt2 = System.DateTime.Now
let b2 = System.DateTime.TryParse("12-20-04 12:21:00", &dt2)
```

Where the `&` operator finds the memory address of dt2 in order to modify the reference.

Here's some [additional information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) on F# parameter syntaxt.

Comment: that's not the preferred way, please don't use the mutable dt2 there

Comment: @Alex, OP wants to use a mutable DateTime as the second argument. I agree that you can call DateTime.Parse much more cleanly, but that isn't the question that was asked.

Answer (score 10):

Just for the sake of completeness, yet another option is to use ref cells, e.g.

```
let d = ref System.DateTime.MinValue
if (System.DateTime.TryParse("1/1/1", d)) then
   // ...
```

Comment: This is better than mutables, as you aren't limited to the current scope.

Comment: Not according to Don Syme (https://github.com/dsyme/fsharp-presentations/blob/master/2018-09-27-openfsharp-code-I-love/fsharp-code-i-love.pptx?raw=true):
"We are planning to deprecate “!” and “:=“ to a compat module in F# 4.5 or 5.0"

Answer (score 6):

I've found one more way, it seems more functional style (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4950763/1349649)

```
match System.DateTime.TryParse "1-1-2011" with
| true, date -> printfn "Success: %A" date
| _ -> printfn "Failed!"
```

Unfirtunately, I can't find any information about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have a helper module I like to include in all my projects.  I collect things like this, putting all the imperative -> functional conversions in one place for reuse:

```
module helper = 
    
    //if some, unwrap input and call fun
    let inline ( |>- ) x f  = Option.bind f x //bind f x
    //if some, unwrap input, call fun, and wrap output 
    let inline ( |>-+ ) x f = Option.map f x 

    module dateTime =

      let tryParse (input: string) : DateTime option =
        let mutable dt = DateTime.Now
        if DateTime.TryParse(input, &dt) then Some dt else None
```