# Using NLoptNet in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, nlopt

Having found no examples online of NLopt being used in F#, I've been trying to convert the example given on [NLoptNet](https://github.com/BrannonKing/NLoptNet) from C# to F#. Having no familiarity with C# and very little with F#, I've been butchering it pretty badly.

Here is what I have so far:

```
open NLoptNet
open System


let solver = new NLoptSolver(NLoptAlgorithm.LN_COBYLA, uint32(1), 0.001, 100)
solver.SetLowerBounds([|-10.0|])
solver.SetUpperBounds([|100.0|])

let objfunc (variables : float array) = 
    Math.Pow(variables.[0] - 3.0, 2.0) + 4.0

solver.SetMinObjective(objfunc)

let initial_val = [|2.|]
let finalscore = ref System.Nullable()   // ERROR
let result = solver.Optimize(initial_val,  finalscore)
```

Here is the description of the error:

> Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and
>   arguments involving function or method applications should be
>   parenthesized

To be more specific, I'm trying to translate the following three lines of C# to F#:

```cs
double? finalScore;
var initialValue = new[] { 2.0 };
var result = solver.Optimize(initialValue, out finalScore);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that `ref (System.Nullable())` or `ref <| System.Nullable()` will solve your problem

Comment: Terrific. Can you please post as answer so I can hit the checkmark? Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if you could take the out parameter without creating a ref cell. something like this `let finalscore, result = solver.Optimize(initial_val)`.

Comment: Hey wow... You're right. I'm assuming ref cells are something to be avoided?

Comment: Generally you don't need to use `ref` from F# 4.0. If you want a mutable you can just say `let mutable x = 5`. For this particular case the out parameter can be deconstructed (pattern matched) on the left side. It's useful for various C# tryParse functions that return true or false for example. Or you can throw it away of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is due to the way that F# handles precedence - adding more brackets or some operators to clarify the order in which things are applied fixes the problem.

2 possible fixes are

```
ref (System.Nullable())
```

or

```
ref <| System.Nullable()
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness' sake here's a third possible fix:

`let finalscore, result = solver.Optimize(initial_val)`

This takes advantage of the fact the F# can treat the out parameter as a return value (in a tuple). I'm sure that there might be a case where an actual ref cell might be necessary. In recent F# `mutable` usually is enough. For some discussion see:

[MSDN reference](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/completeness-seamless-dotnet-interop/)

[SO Discussion 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589311/what-is-the-correct-way-to-call-datetime-tryparse-from-f)

[SO Discussion 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221200/f-let-mutable-vs-ref)

[Fun&Profit reference](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/completeness-seamless-dotnet-interop/)