# Convert String to Date only in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert String to Date in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188585/convert-string-to-date-in-net)

I new here, I'm stuck with this problem when a have an array of strings with values of "120612" and "200612".

I need to convert the strings to a date format like this, "Tues 12 June, 2012". How will I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't googling much more easier that writing this question?

Comment: Or searching SO, there are *tons* of examples

Comment: dont forget to mark it as accepted if you got the info you want...

Answer (score 5):

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) is probably what you're looking for:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("200612", "ddMMyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: +1 Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It works...