# Cannot format Date type data from Database

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

When I get information from the database, I can't format the Date type information.

I'm using:

```
while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    var payment = new Payment
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(sqlReader["Id"]),
        Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(sqlReader["Amount"]),
        StartDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["StartDay"]), //I want this to get this format dd.MM.yyyy
        EndDay = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["EndDay"]) //I want this to get this format dd.MM.yyyy
    };

    Payments.Add(payment);
}
```

I tried my extension methods: `.ToShortDate()`, tried `DateTime.ParseExact`, I keep getting this : `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: can you show the database values for `StartDay` and `EndDay`?

Comment: Does your Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["StartDay"]) works, but just not returning the desired format or does not working at all?

Comment: @GianAcuna  Their database type is "date", and their values are saved as "yyyy.dd.mm"

Comment: @kostasch. Yes, it is working, but it is not return the desired format. I only want the date to show in datagrid like this "dd.MM.yyyy", but it shows like "mm.dd.yyyy + time"

Comment: use the api as mentioned in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188585/convert-string-to-date-in-net.

Comment: @Etrit your `StartDay` is type of DateTime, so to display it, you have to format that DateTime, What is the control used to display it? Any binding?

Comment: @KingKing I'm giving the datagrid's datasource this list "Payments".

Comment: @Etrit if so, you have to find the column which displays that DateTime and change its `DefaultCellStyle.Format` accordingly such as `DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy"`, that should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the above example which in order to work have to change your data type of StartDay,EndDay  from `DateTime` to `string`

```
 StartDay = sqlReader["StartDay"] != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(sqlReader["StartDay"]).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") : new Date(DateTime.Now.Year,01,01);
```

Comment: `StartDay` is type of `DateTime` so how can you assign a string to it?

Comment: your update requires the OP to change his DataGridViewColumn of DateTime to DataGridViewColumn of string, it's not the perfect solution though :>

Comment: @KingKing I agree with you. The best solution is the one you provide as comment. To change it from grid style.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
[DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) or [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sample for Oracle.DataAccess:

```
DateTime value=default(DateTime);
if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
     value= reader.GetDateTime(1);
```

1- number of column

Comment: What's this? The OP wants to display a DateTime value with format `dd.MM.yyyy`, his problem is formating a DateTime value but he didn't think that involves the control used to display the DateTime value, the DateTime value is a persistent structure, we can just change the Text representing a DateTime value via a Control using some kind of format.

Comment: You can easy convert DateTime to formated string use '.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")'

Comment: and how is that string used then? it should be used by some control to display/show to user. In fact, some control has some kind of integrated `ToString(...)` to format the value accordingly depending on some property for example, a DataGridViewColumn has a `DefaultCellStyle.Format`, that's exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: @King King. i read comments to question. I think that your comment is right. But when i posted that answer i didn't see that comment

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) passing in a culture format:

```
StartDay = DateTime.Parse("2013/06/19", new CultureInfo("en-GB", false));
```

Gives a date:

> 19/06/2013 00:00:00

You can remove the hour/min/seconds by calling `.ToShortDateString()` on it if needed.

Actually, you should be able to get the date from the DB as normal and then control how it's output on the frontend by calling `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` on it.

```
Response.Write(StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Comment: This changes `CultureInfo`, which will affect how `ToString()` works but that's not a general way to format the value as whatever you want. However in this case the OP wants `dd.MM.yyyy` so this works.

Comment: Actually, it shouldn't matter what format the date comes back in from the DB. He can control how it's displayed on the frontend using a simple `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` on the date object.