# How to get a MongoDB BsonDocument from a collection based on last timestamp and some other filters using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

For a building security system I want to get the last swiped card time for a particular student based on their id serial number. I am using this code

```
var _collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("entrycard_swipetimes");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("studentid", "stu-1234") & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Carddetails.LastSwipeTimestamp", "2021-11-25T10:50:00.5230694Z");
var doc = _collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is a snippet of the json document

```
{
  "studentid"; "stu-1234",
  "Carddetails": 
   { 
      "LastSwipeTimestamp": "2021-11-25T10:50:00.5230694Z"
    }
}
```

The code above works and I get a record, but I need to know the exact time string in advance. How can get only the last time a particular student swiped their card? How do I get the last timestamp of all the students in the system and have it paged by say 20 students at a time for the last 30 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `Filter` and add a sort thusly:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("studentid", "stu-1234");

var doc = _collection.Find(filter).Sort("{\"Carddetails.LastSwipeTimestamp\":-1}").FirstOrDefault();
```

Highly recommend that you change `Carddetails.LastSwipeTimestamp` to be a real datetime type instead of an ISO8601 string.

Comment: I am currently storing them as a document using the incoming json string `data` like so `var bsonDoc = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(data);`
            `var document = new BsonDocument().AddRange(bsonDoc);` 
`_collection.InsertOneAsync(document);`
How do I store the date in the json string data as Date type?

Comment: Check out 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188585/convert-string-to-date-in-net-if-my-incoming-date-format-is-in-yyyymmdd
After you create `document`, navigate through the document (a `Dictionary` type) to where `LastSwipeTimestamp` is and replace it with the parsed datetime version before calling `InsertOneAsync`.

Comment: NOTE:  MongoDB will only store milliseconds, not microseconds, so a successful parse of `2021-11-25T10:50:00.5230694Z` will end up in MongoDB as `ISODate(2021-11-25T10:50:00.523Z)`

Comment: Thanks. Can you add to your answer how to get the last timestamp for every student ? that would make your answer complete.

Comment: ?   The `Sort` after the `Find` in my answer above coupled with `FirstOrDefault` will return the last (most recent) timestamp.

Comment: Thanks. Getting an error on the sort `Invalid Json Input`. The date is being saved as ISODate(2021-11-25T10:50:00.523Z) format when I breakpoint to that spot, but when I pull up the record in Mongodb client the date looks like this `2021-11-25T10:50:00.000+00:00` ...Not sure whats going on.

Comment: Whoops.   Copy-and-paste error.  You need extra escaped quotes for dotpath notation.   Answer above modified for `Sort`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the last time a particular student (`studentId`) swiped their card:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("studentid", studentId);
var doc = collection
    .Find(filter)
    .SortByDescending(bson => bson["Carddetails.LastSwipeTimestamp"])
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

To get the last timestamp of all the students in the system and have it paged by `pageSize` students at a time for the last `lastDaysCount` days:

```
var doc = collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Group(new BsonDocument
    {
        { "_id", "$studentid" },
        {
            "LastSwipeTimestamp", new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$max", "$Carddetails.LastSwipeTimestamp" }
            }
        },
    })
    .Match(bson => bson["LastSwipeTimestamp"] > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-lastDaysCount))
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Limit(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

But for this to work, you should store your dates as `Date` type.

Comment: I am currently storing them as a document using the incoming json string `data` like so `var bsonDoc = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(data);`
            `var document = new BsonDocument().AddRange(bsonDoc);` 
`_collection.InsertOneAsync(document);`
How do I store the date in the json string data as Date type?